# Prove that $\{ x_n \}^\infty_{i=0}$ where $x_n = r^n$ is a Cauchy sequence (where $0<r<1$)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I do understand how to prove that it is a Cauchy sequence, but I do not know how to apply the method to this sequence.

Comment: It converges, so must be Cauchy.

Comment: If you do understand how to prove a sequence is Cauchy but can't do it for this sequence, please show the working you have done so far and clarify **exactly** where your difficulty lies.  If you don't do this then it is impossible for anyone to give you useful help.

Comment: Your personal page shows that you have asked 6 questions so far (maybe others have been deleted). **None of them fulfills the requirements of the site** that @David is alluding to. Why is that? Of course, you can continue to behave outside of the rules but then, please do not act surprised if you do not get from the site as much as you would want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n>m$ then
$0 < x_m-x_n =r^m-r^n
=r^m(1-r^{n-m})
<r^m$.

Therefore all that is needed to show
$r^m \to 0$,

I read this in
"What is Mathematics" years ago:

Since $0<r<1$, let $r=1/(1+a)$
where $a>0$.
By Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+a)^m > 1+ma >ma$
so $r^m < 1/(ma)
\to 0$.